# json schema - how to indicate that attribute is good to have (not mandatory but not totally optional)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Hi I am writing a Json Schema, I want errors in two categories

Must have attributes are missing - if the json is missing these attributes, we will log and buzz the alerts BUT wont send that json to client

Good to have attributes are missing - if the json is missing these attributes, we will log, buzz the alerts and will send data to client

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, please?  It would give us more direction on how to help.